# Is there any Visual Library alternative to wxPython that supports CSS/Style Sheets?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've developed a program that extensively uses wxPython - the wxWindow port for python.

Even though it is as mature library it is still very primitive and very programming oriented. Which is time consuming and not flexible at all.

I would love to see if there is something like Flex/Action Script where all the visual dimensions are configured by style sheets.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) with [Qt style sheets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/stylesheet.html) might be a good fit. Naturally, you'd need to re-write quite a bit of your GUI layer for the toolkit change.

Comment: Thank You. It seems a very interesting library. I know I will have to re-do a lot of work, but the app is well structured in different layers, and won't be that hard. I will take a look on that with more details to see if covers all app needs in matter of components. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try XUL, the language the Firefox GUI uses.  It's XML styled with CSS and scripted with Javascript.

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL
http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL